# How to remove launchpad icon of broken application

Tags: macports, launchpad

I installed gimp from macports and uninstalled it (`port uninstall gimp`) when I found its not well maintained as gimp released its native mac build. But the gimp icon in launchpad didn't go away. How can I force remove the gimp's leftover launchpad icon? I tried moving it to trash and failed. I also tried to wiggle the launchpad icons to click on the 'x' mark but I didn't find 'x' mark on it. OSX 10.9.2 MacBook Air.

Comment: sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db "DELETE from apps WHERE title='APP_NAME';" && killall Dock

Comment: @Buscar `sqlite3: Error: too many options: "DELETE from apps WHERE title='GIMP';"`

Comment: @Buscar `$ sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db
SQLite version 3.8.4.3 2014-04-03 16:53:12
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> DELETE from apps WHERE title='GIMP';
Error: no such table: apps'`

Comment: be careful, you could delete all apps, then you would have to start over (repopulating them)

Comment: @Buscar ok I don't experiment;ur suggestion didn't work.

Comment: then your 'GIMP' is called something else, try this http://launchpadmanager.com/features.php

Comment: or try the 'mdfind gimp' in terminal to find the leftovers. follow those instructions here for manual removal http://www.uninstallapp.org/uninstall-gimp-how-to-remove-gimp-from-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

### [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com)

Launchpad Manager will allow you to delete any app from your Launchpad. Just open it, select GIMP and ⌘⌫.

[image: Launchpad Manager Image]